# No ConvertAll for LinkedList<T>?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, linked-list, converters

Does anyone have an extension method to quickly convert the types in a `LinkedList<T>` using a `Converter<TInput, TOutput>`?

I'm a bit surprised, where is the `ConvertAll<TOutput>(delegate)`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `ConvertAll` equivalent in extension methods for Linq is called `Select`!

```
var result = myLinkedList.Select(x => FancyCalculationWith(x))
```

Comment: Assuming, of course, that LinkedList<T> implements IEnumerable<T>.  I am not familiar with LinkedList<T>

Comment: (The difference being that List.ConvertAll is able to pre-allocate a buffer of the right size of course, as it knows the existing size.)

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you want to get out of it, but you can use Cast then enumerate through the resulting IEnumerable.

```
  public class Foo
  {
    ...
  }

  public class Bar : Foo
  {
    ...
  }

  var list = new LinkedList<Bar>();
  .... make list....

  foreach (var foo in list.Cast<Foo>())
  {
      ...
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

As [tvanfosson says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/735543/no-convertall-for-linkedlistt/735651#735651) it is possible to `Cast<T>` but if you want to avoid an `InvalidCastException` you can use the [`OfType<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx) extension method which will silently pass over and items in the list that fail the conversion to the type of the generic type parameter you supply.